# Adjusting 2D screen coordinate system for OpenGLES in iOS after a UIDeviceOrientation change

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have an iOS OpenGLES 2D project (draws sprites) in which I successfully detect a UIDeviceOrientation change.  I believe I next need to adjust the screen coordinates accordingly based on the device's orientation and I wonder if anyone has any tricks or insight on the best way to do so.

I can, of course, do some conversion for each orientation and feed that into the code that draws to OpenGLES, but that seems overly complicated.  It would mean having some type of logic to custom rotate every drawing and keep track of direction of sprites differently for each orientation.

I just wonder if anyone has ideas on the most effective way to do this. (want to make sure we're not over thinking it).  The greatest solution would be one were the screen coordinates reset to the default orientation's coordinate system automatically for each orientation.  But, doing it manually is certainly doable.